# Under what circumstances will ` __esModule` be added to a module by webpack?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

This question occurs to me when I found `import A from './A'` will go to get the `default` property of the module. So I looked into the bundled file, and find the module A doesn't have any `.default` property due to `__esModule` is added somehow by webpack... So my question is **Under what circumstances will `__esModule` be added**?